# Tampermonkey Remove specific Content

Tags: tampermonkey

I would like to remove things from the main page but the information I need is stored on the next site. How do I approach this?

This is stored on the first page where I can see all articles and all links in href have different numbers, sometimes numbers and letters.

```
<div class="NewsArticle">
<div class="featured-content-image">
    <a href="/27312/72410214/" rel="bookmark">
        <img class="imageclass" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" data-original"https/domainname.com/2021/0/Article01.jpg" src="https/domainname.com/2021/0/Article01.jpg" alt="Article01" style="display: inline;">
        <div class="link-overlay"></div>
    </a>
    <span class"article-views">170392 Views</span>
</div>
```

This is on the second site where, for example, "military" is stored for whatever reason. Is it possible to remove the articles that contain "military"?

```
<a title="military" href="/category/military" rel="tag" style="margin-right:3px;margin-bottom:3px;" class="btn btn-info btn-md">military</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can do something like

`$("div").remove()`

this selects all the divs and removes them

or you can do

`$( "div:contains('military')" ).remove()`

this looks at all divs if the divs have military in it it is then removed

IMPORTANT:

Make sure to have

`// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js`

And declare the variable

`/* globals jQuery, $, waitForKeyElements */`